# What are cars called that look stock but have lots of performance modifications in Japan? Americans call them Sleepers

Tags: slang

What are cars called that look stock but have lots of performance modifications in Japan? Americans call them Sleepers.

Answer (score 1):

チューニングカー (from "tuning car") or チューンドカー (from "tuned car").

From [JMdict / EDICT](https://www.edrdg.org/wiki/index.php/JMdict-EDICT_Dictionary_Project) (edict2u) dictionary:

> チューニングカー;チューンドカー /(n) tuned car/modified car/EntL2831780/

Comment: This would be the closest, but it's worth noting that チューニングカー doesn't convey the meaning of the "look stock" part. It just refers to cars with performance modifications, *with or without exterior changes*.

Comment: Dictionary does not have any other entries for such cars...

Comment: You might be correct. However, if emphasizing the "look stock" aspect is vital, we can employ a similar approach as used when [translating "weeaboo"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62235/5010). You could use スリーパー and then provide an explanation of its intended meaning (either in parentheses or in a separate sentence).

Comment: @naruto What about **普通外観の**チューンドカー? Normal meaning of "sleeper" is "person who sleeps", and I would dislike adapting some rare slang meaning.

Comment: Yes something like 普通の外観のチューンドカー and ノーマルな外観のチューンアップカー is short enough and descriptive enough at the same time (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19379/5010) as for why it's better to keep の). I'm not a car fan, but I found this definition of *sleeper* is already in ALC, Wikipedia, and so on, so it probably doesn't to have to be dismissed as "some rare slang".

Comment: "Sleeper" is definitely not slang, it's often used in the UK performance car magazines. The term is derived from the idea that nobody would guess that the car has been "hopped up" just by looking at it. So, non-descript saloon cars are often a good choice assuming that they have been left "stock" and don't have obviously flashy wheels or enormous spoilers on them.